# Is it a good idea to factor out LaTeX-mode-hook?

Tags: emacs, coding-style, latex, elisp, auctex

Is it a good idea to factor out `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook)`? What are the advantages and disadvantage when doing this.

For example you could write:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
;;(add-to-list [...]
)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode)

;;[...lots of other LaTeX config stuff]

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

or one could factor out the `LaTeX-mode-hook` statement and write something like this:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()

;;(add-to-list) [...]

(TeX-PDF-mode)

;;[...lots of other LaTeX config stuff]

(flyspell-mode)
))
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to your question: factoring and using a lambda.

I find that factoring is a good idea because it is easier to maintain a `.emacs` file where there is a single location where the hook is added. However, using a `lambda` for this purpose is slightly frowned upon. If you look at the value of the hook after you used a `lambda` you will see that it is "ugly". Furthermore it will be harder to work on that hook. For example, you sometimes want to disable a hook with `remove-hook`. It is easier to do so when you have named your hook explicitely instead of using a lambda.

Comment: Agreed 100%. Use something like `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-mode-hook)` `(defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook () ...)` so that when you want to make changes you can simply re-evaluate the definition of that function rather than having to `remove-hook` the old lambda expression and then `add-hook` a modified version.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that it matters much: you can check this by
e.g. evaluating `LaTeX-mode-hook` in `*scratch*` with both types of statements.
It will look slightly different, but the executing behavior should be the same.

One advantage of keeping it in one `lambda` is that it's easier to maintain.